# Fusing different input channels in caffe?

Tags: caffe

I'd like to process different types of data seperately first and then fuse them in a common layer. Is this possible in Caffe and if yes what would be the best way to do it?

I've read that one can define several data layers in the same prototxt file. But how to fuse them?

Can I just create a `InnerProduct` layer and specify several `bottom` layers? Or do I have to concatenate the individual layers first using a `Concat` layer?

For any small code example I would be very thankful!

Comment: This depends on what kind of fusion you want to do: sum, concat, average?

Comment: I want to to concatenate the several input streams into one layer

Comment: The you need to use a ```Concat``` layer. If you look at the code of ```InnerProduct```, it considers the first input only: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cpp#L80-L93

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and post a code example as answer as soon as its working. If you want an accept for your help you can also post something (I cannot accept a comment ;) )

Comment: @mcExchange, by any chance, did you only have one output label for the multiple inputs? If so, how did you handle it? I have 2 input images but the output is a single image.

Comment: @user3126802 I guess you can to concatenate the two input images and store them to disk before loading them into caffe. In caffe you can then split the images and process them in different layers.

Comment: @mcExchange so what you're saying is, assuming only grayscale images (therefore one channel), concatenate them such that i have 2 channels in the input,(and only one label for the output), then use a split layer?

Comment: @user3126802 yes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, `InnerProduct` works with a single input. The fusion (concatenation) can then be done in a specific `Concat` layer with a configuration like this:

```
layer {
  name: "concat"
  bottom: "in1"
  bottom: "in2"
  top: "out"
  type: "Concat"
  concat_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
```

The official documentation has more details about that layer: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html